# java, is there a way we can import a class under another name

Tags: java, syntactic-sugar, import

is there a way we can import a class under another name?
Like if i have a class called javax.C and another class called java.C i can import javax.C under the name C1 and import java.C under the name C2.

We can do something like this in C#:

```
using Sys=System;
```

or Vb:

```
Imports Sys=System
```

Comment: You can do this in Scala. Like this:
import java.util.{ArrayList => JavaList}

Comment: There is a draft JEP (JDK Enhancement Proposals) about that [Change name of imported type (aliasing)](https://gist.github.com/cardil/b29a81efd64a09585076fe00e3d34de7)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

No, there is nothing like that in Java. You can only import classes under their original name, and have to use the fully qualified name for all that you don't import (except those in `java.lang` and the current class's package).

Answer (score 4):

To be short, no, this isn't possible in Java.

Answer (score 2):

No. I think Java *deliberately* ditched `typedef`. The good news is, if you see a type, you know what it is. It can't be an alias to something else; or an alias to an alias to ...

If a new concept really deserves a new name, it most likely deserves a new type also.

The usage example of `Sys=System` will be frowned upon by most Java devs.

Comment: actually that's just an example. a better use case would be importing classes with clashing names (this will happen all the time)

Comment: @Pacerier name clash is not very common in java. and when it happens, use full class name with package name, whose purpose is specifically to resolve name clash.

Comment: i do not believe that the purpose of packages is specifically to resolve name clashes. Packages are for grouping things logically. Name clash is "expected" in OOP, and that's why we have packages/namespaces

Comment: the #1 purpose of package is to prevent name conflicts.

Comment: Name clashes are totally common in Java. So common that it is really annoying not to be able to rename imports. Node, Date, Display, Rectangle, Point, Vector, List, you name it. **I HATE TO WRITE `new qwerty.uiopasdf.ghjkl.yxcvbnm.qetuos.fhjlxvn.Node()`!!!111**

Comment: I'd love it if anyone had actual history documented on this: >> "I think Java deliberately ditched `typedef`"

Answer (score 1):

Java doesn't support static renaming. One idea is to subclass object in question with a new classname (but may not be a good idea because of certain side-effects / limitations, e.g. your target class may have the final modifier. Where permitted the code may behave differently if explicit type checking is used `getClass()` or `instanceof ClassToRename`, etc. (example below adapted from a different answer)

```
class MyApp {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ClassToRename parent_obj = new ClassToRename("Original class");
    MyRenamedClass extended_obj_class_renamed = new MyRenamedClass("lol, the class was renamed");
    // these two calls may be treated as the same
    // * under certain conditions only *
    parent_obj.originalFoo();
    extended_obj_class_renamed.originalFoo();
  }  

  private static class ClassToRename {
    public ClassToRename(String strvar) {/*...*/}
    public void originalFoo() {/*...*/}
  }

  private static class MyRenamedClass extends ClassToRename {
    public MyRenamedClass(String strvar) {super(strvar);}
  }

}
```