# Short name for imported constant class fields

Tags: java, boilerplate

I have a java program with hundreds of configuration constants:

```
public static final String C1="C1";
public static final String C2="C2";
```

Since there are so many of them, I've put them into a separate class, `MyClassConstants`.
Now, I need to use them on `MyClass`:

```
import mynamespace.MyClassConstants;
myMethod( MyClassConstants.C1, MyClassConstants.C2 );
```

This gets very verbose very fast, so I was wondering if it was possible to somehow import the fields directly:

```
import mynamespace.MyClassConstants.*; 
myMethod( C1, C2 ); //doesn't work
```

Or at the very least, rename the import:

```
import mynamespace.MyClassConstants as C; //javac hates me
myMethod( C.C1, C.C2 );
```

But [it seems this later approach is impossible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767864/java-is-there-a-way-we-can-import-a-class-under-another-name)

Is there a way to do this and still have a meaningful class name for the constants? Or should I use another approach?

Comment: Try `import static`

Comment: Are those constants related?

Comment: @RongNK That was fast, and it's exactly what I was looking for! Consider adding that as an answer. A [link to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_import) may be useful too

Comment: @RohitJain yes, they're conceptually inseparable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is `Static import`, you can solve by using it:

`import static mynamespace.MyClassConstants.*;`

**See also**:

- [Static import](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_import)
- [Java doc: static import](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/static-import.html)

Answer (score 6):

try

```
import static mynamespace.MyClassConstants.*;
```

then

```
myMethod( C1, C2 );  should work
```

Answer (score 3):

You should static import.
More details are here http://javapapers.com/core-java/what-is-a-static-import-in-java/

You have it like : `import static mynamespace.MyClassConstants.*;`